# The compareToIgnoreCase method in Java

Tags: java, string, methods

I found this piece of code on the internet and I'm trying to understand it...I don't know why the output is: 
10
-10
-69

```
  String str1 = "Strings are immutable";
  String str2 = "Strings are immutable";
  String str3 = "Integers are not immutable";
  String str4 = "Strings are immutabl ";

  result = str2.compareToIgnoreCase( str3 );
  System.out.println(result);

  result = str3.compareToIgnoreCase( str1 );
  System.out.println(result);

  result = str4.compareToIgnoreCase( str2 );
  System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: i suggest taking a look at the javadoc -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)

Comment: i suggest going through your java textbook before randomly trying codes off internet.

Comment: Post entire code, what is result, str4?

Comment: oops- missed that. The result of str4 is -69

Comment: what is the value of str4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparisons are similar to the ordering that one might find in a dictionary.

The return of this method is an int which can be interpreted as follows:

returns < 0 then the String calling the method is lexicographically first (comes first in a dictionary)

returns == 0 then the two strings are lexicographically equivalent

returns > 0 then the parameter passed to the compareTo method is lexicographically first.

**More specifically, the method provides the first non-zero difference in ASCII values.**

Thus "comp**u**ter".compareTo ("comp**a**rison") will return a value of (int) '**u**' - (int) '**a**' (21). Since this is a positive result, the parameter ("comparison") is lexicographically first.

For your example:

```
result = str4.compareToIgnoreCase( str2 );
```

will return -69 because in [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)  Decimal SPACE has the value 32 and 'e' has the value 101. If you compare str4 with str2, the only difference is the last character ' ' for str4 and 'e' for str2. So you calculate (int) 'SPACE' 32 - (int) 'e' 101 = -69. Since the rest of these two strings are equals, it's 0 + (-69) = -69.

Answer (score 2):

Compares two strings lexicographically, ignoring case differences. The comparison is based on the Unicode value of each character in the strings. The character sequence represented by this String object is compared lexicographically to the character sequence represented by the argument string. The result is a negative integer if this `String` object lexicographically precedes the argument string. The result is a positive integer if this `String` object lexicographically follows the argument string. The result is zero if the strings are equal; compareTo returns 0 exactly when the `equals(Object)` method would return `true`.

Answer (score -2):

Is it from this link? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_comparetoignorecase.htm

Well, there's an example for

```
str2.compareToIgnoreCase( str3 );

str3.compareToIgnoreCase( str1 );
```

for

```
str4.compareToIgnoreCase( str2 );
```

it returns -69 because str4 is less than str2.

Check this link http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=220